# How to pre-populate a form on Site B with data from Site A

Tags: php, forms

I'm wondering if it's possible to pre-populate a form via PHP (POST/GET, etc) that's on Site B and I'm getting the data on Site A.

So Site A is **my own website** and I **do not own** Site B. I want visitors to enter their email address on Site A and then redirect them to Site B where I want to pre-populate this email on their forms.

Is that somehow possible? Or it's depending on Site B?

Comment: You should pass them in url and Site B need to change their code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is impossible.

As someone running a website, there is no way for you to control what another website (which you do not control) will send to one of their visitors.

If it was possible, it would be a huge security problem.

You would need the cooperation of Site B to achieve what you want.

Comment: I got an idea about running site B as a frame inside site A and somehow populate it by javascript. But that is bulky and unreliable solution

Comment: @PavelJanicek — No. It isn't unreliable, it simply won't work. You'll get a security exception when you attempt to access the cross-origin frame.